# Snake game as console app in c++

Tags: c++, object-oriented, snake-game

I made a snake game as console aplication. It was my first real little project I did all alone. I tried using best practices I learned but I've got lost few times so I suppose there will be some bad practices and bugs. I would like if someone has time to review my code and tell me what I did wrong so I can improve. I did everything in file, I hope its not a problem for reader.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <conio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <random>

using namespace std::chrono_literals; // for ms

// map dimensions
constexpr int mapHeight{ 15 };
constexpr int mapWidth{ 30 };

void gameOver(); // foward declaration instead moving whole definition to the top

enum class Objects {
    wall,
    snake,
    fruit,
    empty,
};

using mapType = std::array<std::array<Objects, mapWidth>, mapHeight>;

//filling map with walls and empty space for beginning
void fillMap(mapType& map) {
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < mapHeight; ++i) {
        for (int j{ 0 }; j < mapWidth; ++j) {
            if (i == 0 || i == mapHeight - 1 || j == 0 || j == mapWidth - 1) map[i][j] = Objects::wall;
            else map[i][j] = Objects::empty;
        }
    }
}
//printing map as it modifies through the game
void printMap(const mapType& map) {
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < mapHeight; ++i) {
        for (int j{ 0 }; j < mapWidth; ++j) {
            switch (map[i][j]) {
                case Objects::wall: std::cout << "#";
                    break;
                case Objects::snake: std::cout << "o";
                    break;
                case Objects::fruit: std::cout << "F";
                    break;
                default: std::cout << " ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

class Fruit {
private:
    static int getRandomInt(int a, int b);
    static  bool m_isSpawned;
public:

    static void spawn(mapType& map);
    static bool isSpawned();
    static void spawnedFalse(); 
    static void spawnedTrue();
};
bool Fruit::m_isSpawned = true; // true because game starts with spawned fruit
int Fruit::getRandomInt(int a, int b) {

    static std::random_device randDev;
    static std::mt19937 twister(randDev());
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist;

    dist.param(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type(a, b));
    return dist(twister);

}
void Fruit::spawn(mapType& map) {
    //spawning anywhere empty
    while (true) {
        int y{ getRandomInt(1, mapHeight - 2) };
        int x{ getRandomInt(1,mapWidth - 2) };
        if (map[y][x] == Objects::empty) {
            map[y][x] = Objects::fruit;
            return;
        }
    }
}
bool Fruit::isSpawned() {
    return m_isSpawned;
}
void Fruit::spawnedFalse() {
    m_isSpawned = false;
}
void Fruit::spawnedTrue() {
    m_isSpawned = true;
}


class Snake {
public:
    enum class Direction {
        up,
        right,
        down,
        left,
    };
private:
    struct Coordinates {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    std::vector<Coordinates> m_snakesBody{};
    Coordinates m_frontPosition{};
    int m_startLength{ 3 };
    Direction m_direction{Direction::right};  
    static int m_score;
    
public:
    
    Snake(mapType& map);  //begining snakes position
    void move(mapType& map); // controls snakes movement
    void takeDirectionsByUserInput(); // enables user to control snake directions using WSAD keys
    void eraseTail(mapType& map); //erases last 'o' on the snake as the snake moves 

    //adds 'o' on in direction where snake is going, so it can move ahead
    void addHeadToRight( mapType& map); 
    void addHeadToDown( mapType& map);
    void addHeadToLeft( mapType& map);
    void addHeadToUp( mapType& map);    

    void eat(mapType& map); // increases score and tells us snake has eaten
    static int getScore(); 
};
int Snake::m_score = 0;
Snake::Snake (mapType& map) {
    // /2 so snake appears in the middle
    int y{ mapHeight / 2 };
    int x{ mapWidth / 2 - 1 };
    
    
    //setting snake in the starting position by changing middle Object::empty into Object::snake
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < m_startLength; ++i) {
        map[y][x] = Objects::snake;
        Coordinates coo{ x,y };
        m_snakesBody.push_back(coo);
        ++x;

    }
    m_frontPosition.x = x - 1;
    m_frontPosition.y = y;

}


void Snake::eraseTail(mapType& map) {
    //accesing x and y of first element in vector (back of the snake)
    int backX{ m_snakesBody.front().x };
    int backY{ m_snakesBody.front().y };

    //removing last part of snake so we can move ahead
    map[backY][backX] = Objects::empty;
    m_snakesBody.erase(m_snakesBody.begin());
}
void Snake::addHeadToRight( mapType& map) {
    //checking if snake is moving into its body or wall, game over if it does
    //x+1 because snake is going right
    if (map[m_frontPosition.y][m_frontPosition.x + 1] == Objects::snake
        || map[m_frontPosition.y][m_frontPosition.x + 1] == Objects::wall) {
        gameOver();
    }

    if (map[m_frontPosition.y][m_frontPosition.x + 1] == Objects::fruit) eat(map); //if snakes next field is fruit, eat it
    //making one place in the right snake body if theres no colision
    map[m_frontPosition.y][m_frontPosition.x + 1] = Objects::snake;
    //pushing back new fornt in the vector as the snake goes forward
    int newFrontX{ m_frontPosition.x + 1 };
    int newFrontY{ m_frontPosition.y };
    Coordinates newFront = { newFrontX, newFrontY };
    m_snakesBody.push_back(newFront);
    //increasing on x axis as we move right
    m_frontPosition.x += 1;
}
void Snake::addHeadToDown(mapType& map) {
    //checking if snake is moving into its body or wall, game over if it does
    if (map[m_frontPosition.y + 1][m_frontPosition.x] == Objects::snake
        || map[m_frontPosition.y + 1][m_frontPosition.x] == Objects::wall) {
        gameOver();
    }
    if (map[m_frontPosition.y + 1][m_frontPosition.x] == Objects::fruit) eat(map);
    //making one place down snake body if theres no colision
     map[m_frontPosition.y + 1][m_frontPosition.x] = Objects::snake;
    //pushing back new fornt in the vector
    int newFrontX{ m_frontPosition.x };
    int newFrontY{ m_frontPosition.y + 1 };
    Coordinates newFront = { newFrontX, newFrontY };
    m_snakesBody.push_back(newFront);
    //increasing on y axis as we move down
    m_frontPosition.y += 1;
}
void Snake::addHeadToLeft(mapType& map) {
    //checking if snake is moving into its body or wall, game over if it does
    if (map[m_frontPosition.y][m_frontPosition.x - 1] == Objects::snake
        || map[m_frontPosition.y][m_frontPosition.x - 1] == Objects::wall) {
        gameOver();
    }
    if (map[m_frontPosition.y][m_frontPosition.x - 1] == Objects::fruit) eat(map);
    //making one place in the left snake body if theres no colision
    map[m_frontPosition.y][m_frontPosition.x - 1] = Objects::snake;
    //pushing back new fornt in the vector
    int newFrontX{ m_frontPosition.x - 1 };
    int newFrontY{ m_frontPosition.y };
    Coordinates newFront = { newFrontX, newFrontY };
    m_snakesBody.push_back(newFront);
    //reducing on x axis as we move left
    m_frontPosition.x -= 1;
}
void Snake::addHeadToUp(mapType& map) {
    //checking if snake is moving into its body or wall, game over if it does
    if (map[m_frontPosition.y - 1][m_frontPosition.x] == Objects::snake
        || map[m_frontPosition.y - 1][m_frontPosition.x] == Objects::wall) {
        gameOver();
    }
    if (map[m_frontPosition.y - 1][m_frontPosition.x] == Objects::fruit) eat(map);
    //making one place up snake body if theres no colision
    map[m_frontPosition.y - 1][m_frontPosition.x] = Objects::snake;
    //pushing back new fornt in the vector
    int newFrontX{ m_frontPosition.x };
    int newFrontY{ m_frontPosition.y - 1 };
    Coordinates newFront = { newFrontX, newFrontY };
    m_snakesBody.push_back(newFront);
    //reducing y axis as we move up
    m_frontPosition.y -= 1;
}
void Snake::move(mapType& map) {
    switch (m_direction) {
    case Direction::right: {
        
        // changing snakes position on the map as it moves to the right
        addHeadToRight(map);
        //snake grows in tail if it ate (so we are not erasing it if there isn't fruit spawned what means snake ate)
        if((Fruit::isSpawned())){
            eraseTail(map);
        }
       

       
        break;
        }
    case Direction::down: {
        // changing snakes position on the map as it moves down
        addHeadToDown(map);      
        //snake grows in tail if it ate (so we are not erasing it if there isn't fruit spawned what means snake ate)
        if ((Fruit::isSpawned())) {
            eraseTail(map);
        }
        
        break;
        }
    case Direction::left: {
        // changing snakes position on the map as it moves to the left
        addHeadToLeft(map);
        //snake grows in tail if it ate (so we are not erasing it if there isn't fruit spawned what means snake ate)
        if ((Fruit::isSpawned())) {
            eraseTail(map);
        }
      
        break;
    }
    case Direction::up: {
        // changing snakes position on the map as it moves up
         addHeadToUp(map);
         //snake grows in tail if it ate (so we are not erasing it if there isn't fruit spawned what means snake ate)
        if ((Fruit::isSpawned())) {
            eraseTail(map);
        }
       
        
        break;
            }
        }
}

void Snake::takeDirectionsByUserInput() {
   
    //ifs forbid going in opposite direction (turning down while going up etc)
    switch (_getch()) {
    case 'w': if (m_direction != Direction::down) {
       
        m_direction = Direction::up;
    }
        break;
    case 'd': if (m_direction != Direction::left) {
       
        m_direction = Direction::right;
    }
        break;
    case 's': if (m_direction != Direction::up) {
      
        m_direction = Direction::down;
    }
        break;
    case 'a': if (m_direction != Direction::right) {
       
        m_direction = Direction::left;
    }
        break;
     
    }
}


void Snake::eat(mapType& map) {
    ++m_score;
    Fruit::spawnedFalse();
}
int Snake::getScore() {
    return m_score;
}
void set_cursor(int x = 0, int y = 0)
{
    HANDLE handle;
    COORD coordinates;
    handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    coordinates.X = x;
    coordinates.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(handle, coordinates);
}
void gameOver() {
    std::cout << "You lose, you scored " << Snake::getScore();
    std::exit(0);
}
void playGame(mapType& map, Snake& snake) {
   
    Fruit::spawn(map);
    printMap(map);
    
    system("pause"); // waits for user input so it doesn't start automatically
    while (true) {
        set_cursor(); // cursor goes back and 0,0 and we overwrite old map with old map (used instead system("cls") for less flashing
        printMap(map);
        std::cout << Snake::getScore();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(150ms); // pauses program for 150 ms
        if (_kbhit()) { // true if user hit key          
            snake.takeDirectionsByUserInput();
            snake.move(map);
            
            
        }
        else {
            snake.move(map);
        }
        if (!(Fruit::isSpawned())) {
            
            Fruit::spawn(map);
            Fruit::spawnedTrue();
        }
        

    }
}
int main()
{
    mapType map{};
    fillMap(map);
    Snake snake(map);
   
    playGame(map, snake);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ivica, is this program running on Windows? You use `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE`, `Windows.h` header should be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good.  The items I'm going to flag are minor or because I'm an old school developer and not fully comfortable with all this modern C++ shiz. :)

1. It appears that all your code is in one file.  Its OK for this but
   what if you wanted to reuse the Fruit class.  Personally I would
   split out your classes into separate h/cpp files to improve reuse
   and increase clarity.
2. It will help you in the future if you have a
   comment describing the overall purpose of the class, I know in this
   case its very trivial, but its a good habit to get into.
3. Personally I don't think there are enough comments through out the
   code.  Comments are a really easy way of explaining what the code is
   supposed to do and unlike documents they are stored with the code
   and are more likely to get updated .
4. I don't like code that isn't in
   braces{} like `map[i][j]` I have been burnt to many times in the
   past by someone adding a second line to the if statement.  Its
   stupid but it happens under pressure.
5. The formatting in the `Snake::move()` function is confusing. I would
   have defined a game class and had the constructor run the code that
   is in main (also contains playGame)
6. You have hardcoded the control keys and the characters that
   represent the map, snake and fruit.  If you had them as variables,
   you could allow the user to change the keys or support
   accessibility.
7. Rather than `Fruit::spawnedTrue()` why not have
   `Fruit::setSpawned(const bool flag) {m_isSpawned = flag;}`
8. If you added a constructor to the structs, a) it would make sure the
   PODs were initialised safely and b) it would make the code a bit
   shorter and cleaner.

I'm going to say it again, your code is good, I would be happy if I wrote code like this.  Everything listed above is trivial, ignore it if you want, you will still have good code.